# functions.sh missing on Shopware 6.5.3.3 when calling watch-administration

Tags: shopware6, symfony-flex

We upgraded a shop to 6.5.3.3 from 6.4 and use the Symfony flex template. In the flex system, the scripts which were earlier in the development or production template, were decomposed to recipes.

When calling watch administration I get:

```
$ bin/watch-administration.sh 
bin/watch-administration.sh: line 9: bin/functions.sh: No such file or directory
bin/watch-administration.sh: line 13: load_dotenv: command not found
```

I found the functions.sh here:

https://github.com/shopware/recipes/blob/main/shopware/platform/6.4/bin/functions.sh

But this seems to be in the recipe for `shopware/platform`.

In our project shopware/platform is not installed, which is normal I believe, but

```
        "shopware/administration": "6.5.3.3",
        "shopware/core": "6.5.3.3",
        "shopware/elasticsearch": "6.5.3.3",
        "shopware/storefront": "6.5.3.3",
```

How is the functions.sh supposed to be added? Is this a bug in the flex recipes or am I doing something wrong?

I tried

```
$ composer recipes:install shopware/platform
Run command with -v to see more details

Cannot update: some packages are not installed: shopware/platform
```

which is not working, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is part of `shopware/core` recipe https://github.com/shopware/recipes/blob/main/shopware/core/6.4/bin/functions.sh

The `shopware/platform` recipe is computed by the other packages.

I would reset all recipes to the default values. with composer recipes:reset then the file should be recreated.

Comment: Thanks, there sure was stuff messed up in that installation. I did not find the command `composer recipes:reset`, but I ended up using `composer fix-recipes --force --reset` which seemed to solve it.